# Azure DevOps Services pipeline: error 503 when downloading artifacts from Azure DevOps nuget feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-services

I have a build pipeline that executes a `dotnet restore` for a .net solution. Often, the restore randomly fails with 503 errors like this:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.306/NuGet.targets(156,5): error : Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (The server is busy.). [/src/InvoiceData.Api.sln]
  Failed to download package 'AWSSDK.Core.3.7.100.14' from 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[company name]/_packaging/c8965320-3e6d-42b1-99c9-e2b5151b9986/nuget/v3/flat2/awssdk.core/3.7.100.14/awssdk.core.3.7.100.14.nupkg'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 503 (The server is busy.).
```

Sometimes the restore succeeds when I run the pipeline again.

What is the cause of the 503 error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Look at the Azure DevOps status: https://status.dev.azure.com/ Europe is affected

Comment: @cheesebaron Thanks! It could indeed be  a temporary problem.

Comment: I am seeing the same thing in my builds, so seems temporary 

Answer (score 0):

The problem was probably caused by a service degradation for Azure DevOps Artifacts. The problem disappeared after Microsoft resolved the issue.